# Querying for an object in a list in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using Realm 2.0 (Swift). My model is composed of `X` and `Y` (classes). `X` has a property called `list` which is a Realm List of `Y` objects.

Let's assume I have an instance of a `Y` object, called `y`
The query I'm looking for is:

- What X items contains an object equal to `y` in it's list of `Y` objects?

If the list was just a list of strings, I assume this would be trivial as the query would be: `realm.objects(X.self).filter("<string> IN list")`

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can express this as either:

```
realm.objects(X.self).filter("%@ IN list", y)
```

or:

```
realm.objects(X.self).filter("ANY list = %@", y)
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Any functional difference between `IN` and `ANY`?

Comment: The two are equivalent.